# Consume the REST API of another Spring Boot project locally

Tags: spring-boot, rest, testing, junit

I am building a microservice architecture with different Spring Boot projects and two different repositories for each one of them:

- One application is called `project-api-1`
- The other one `project-api-2`.

Now, within the JUnit tests of `project-api-2` I need to test some functionality that requires making a REST call to the API exposed by `project-api-1`.

Is there a way to link these projects together for testing purposes, in such a way that when I run the tests for `project-api-2` I can also start the `project-api-1` application at runtime, without having to create a mock API of `project-api-1` from scratch within `project-api-2`?

What is the best practice here?

Comment: maybe start project-1 using `testcontainer` or test with contract-driven-tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by running a multi-module Maven project, and importing the REST API project with `<scope>test</scope>`.

In my tests, I then start the Spring Boot application with:

```java
new SpringApplicationBuilder(RestApplication.class)
  .profiles("test")
  .run();
```